# MS word: automatically set document title property to first text with 'title' quick style

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to include the title at the top of each page. The normal title autofield reads the title from the document properties. Is it possible to take the first text with the quick-style 'title' applied to it to be the value of the title autofield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try putting the following nested fields in your page 1 header:

```
{ IF { PAGE } = 1 { SET x { TITLE { STYLEREF Title } } } }
```

All the {} pairs need to be the special field code breaces that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on WIndows Word.

I've never used this, so no idea what unwanted side effects there might be, but

- Instead, you could put the fields { SET X { TITLE { STYLEREF Title }
  } } at the beginning of the document body, but then they are easier
  for a user to damage, and are less likely to update automatically
- The IF { PAGE } = 1 part is there to ensure that you get the first
  Title paragraph (even if it's not on Page 1). It would be easier to
  use separate Page 1 header and just use { SET X { TITLE { STYLEREF
  Title } } }
- The { SET X } is there to hide the result.

Comment: The command works and does what I asked for. However, it doesn't update automatically. I ended up using { STYLEREF Title } everywhere I wanted to place the title. This updates live as I edit the title, so is less confusing to others using my template. Of course the title in the document properties is wrong but we don't use it anyway.

Comment: Sounds like you have what you want. Yes, it doesn't auto-update in the normal sense of the word, but if you're working in Print view and display the header/footer, it will typically update without any further action.